# ruby mysql2 gem installation issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi
 i have to install mysql2 gem for my ruby application. But when i try to install mysql2 gem using "gem install mysql2" it shows an error "Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known". I have already installed mysql @ /usr/bin location. I have run the "gem install mysql2" command from the path /usr/bin, but it shows the same issue.Because of this issues i cannot create my model for ruby on rails project using the command "rails g model contact" it show an error of gem mysql2 is not installed. i have spend long time for googling for tracking this issues, unfortunately no forum have the correct answer. Please help me

Comment: Did you do "bundle install" in this Rails 3 app of yours? It shouldve installed all the required gems. Also need to ensure that your Gemfile has "gem mysql2" in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need the libmysqlclient-dev headers for your system. What kind of OS are you using?

Comment: `libmysqlclient-dev` (in the answer the leading `l` is missing)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on Fedora 14. I needed to install mysql-devel in order to install the mysql2 gem which also installed the the mysql package.