# gem mysql2 gem missing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ruby mysql2 gem installation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509266/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-issues)

I have worked with ruby on rails with mysql2 database. I have installed the the mysql2 gem in my system. I successfully configure my database my database.yml file which is

development:

adapter: mysql2

database: AddressBook

username: root

password: root

host: localhost

pool: 5

timeout: 5000`

but the issues are

1. When i tried to create my model using the command rails g model contact it shows an error

"**Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter) (RuntimeError)**"

like this.

So in order to install mysql2 i have execute the command gem install mysql2. It shows 1 gem installed with a message of "**Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known**"

And one more thing, after installing mysql2 gem file if i am check the existence of mysql2 using command

which mysql2

it again shows no mysql2 is installed with a message

"**/usr/bin/which: no mysql2 in (/usr/lib/ccache:/usr/lib/ccache:/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/zoondia001/bin)**"

If ruby on rails database connection is not possible with mysql2 please tell me another way to connect ruby on rails to database

i am using fedora 13 and installed ruby,ruby on rails and all the gems that are needed for running. Anybody please tell me how track this problem, i am nearly spend my 48 hours for tracking this issues but not getting the solution. please help me

thanks

Comment: You should either delete your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509266/ruby-mysql2-gem-installation-issues) since it is the very same, just that the older question has less info. Please read the FAQ also: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
```

in gemfile

Answer (score -1):

Finally it is corrected. I have remove ruby,rails and gem from system and re-install again. Any way thanks for the help

Comment: Please note SO works best if you include your _solution_, too. SO is intended to be a collection of high quality questions and answers, and as it stands, this question is lacking an answer. Thanks.